# Unity upgrade to 2018.1.6 manifest causing android build failure

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have upgraded my Unity project from 2017 to 2018.1.6.

However a error raised is

> "Cannot "  AndroidSDKToolsException: Unable to merge android manifests.

There is already a new folder created in the project Packages and Unity package manager. Also there is no manifest in my project.

Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

set your minimal SDK version (Under Player Settings -> Other Settings) to 24. If this is not possible, you'd have to create a custom AndroidManifest.xml and place it under Assets/Plugins/Android.

Once your main manifest matches the targetSDKVersion of the library your build should succeed.

Try reading this:-

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1283008/android-unable-to-merge-android-manifest-error.html